# How to exclude rows/columns from numpy.ndarray data

Tags: python, numpy

Assume we have a numpy.ndarray data, let say with the shape (100,200), and you also have a list of indices which you want to exclude from the data. How would you do that? Something like this:

```
a = numpy.random.rand(100,200)
indices = numpy.random.randint(100,size=20)
b = a[-indices,:] # imaginary code, what to replace here?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `b = numpy.delete(a, indices, axis=0)`

Source: [NumPy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).

Comment: For a numeric list of indices, `np.delete` uses the `mask` solution that you earlier rejected as taking up too much memory.

Comment: @hpaulj the documentation for `delete` says:
"out : ndarray
        A copy of `arr` with the elements specified by `obj` removed."
Do you mean that it uses a `numpy.ma` masked array? It does not sound like it to me.

Comment: No, not masked array; mask as in boolean index.

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
a = numpy.random.rand(100,200)
indices = numpy.random.randint(100,size=20)
b = a[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(100),indices),:]
```

This avoids creating the `mask` array of same size as your data in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21022753/865169. Note that this example creates a 2D array `b` instead of the flattened array in the latter answer.

A crude investigation of runtime vs memory cost of this approach vs https://stackoverflow.com/a/30273446/865169 seems to suggest that `delete` is faster while indexing with `setdiff1d` is much easier on memory consumption:

```
In [75]: %timeit b = np.delete(a, indices, axis=0)
The slowest run took 7.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.7 µs per loop

In [76]: %timeit c = a[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(100),indices),:]
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.4 µs per loop

In [77]: %memit b = np.delete(a, indices, axis=0)
peak memory: 52.27 MiB, increment: 0.85 MiB

In [78]: %memit c = a[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(100),indices),:]
peak memory: 52.39 MiB, increment: 0.12 MiB
```

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly but works:

```
b = np.array([a[i] for i in range(m.shape[0]) if i not in indices])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
a = numpy.random.rand(100,200)
indices = numpy.random.randint(100,size=20)
mask = numpy.ones(a.shape, dtype=bool)
mask[indices,:] = False
b = a[mask]
```

Comment: This solution needs an array of the exact same size as my original data, which in my case is gigantic. The time and space complexity of this solution is O(n^2), which is not really practical for my data.

Comment: This is essentially method the `np.delete` uses.  Look where it constructs `keep = ones(N, dtype=bool); keep[obj,] = False`.